# Проверка регистра

Tags: javascript

У меня есть js код с игрой "виселица", она работает, но я не могу понять, как мне сделать так, чтобы в независимости от того, в каком регистре игрок ввёл букву, программа её проверяла, и если она подходит, то ставила её. Вроде есть .toUpperCase, но как мне его применить тут, я уже не соображу...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
var words = ["клавиатура", "мышь", "экран", "ноутбук", "каникулы", "сайт", "кот", "дом", "лес", "еда"];      // Список отгадываемых слов
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];                     // Рандомный выбор слова
var answer = [];

for (var x = 0; x < word.length; x++) {       // проверяем, все ли буквы отгадал игрок
    answer[x] = "_";                        
}

var left = word.length;  
var tries = 5;                          // Количество попыток

while (left > 0 && tries > 0) {          // Цикл, который будет выполнятся до тех пор, пока не слово не будет отгаданно, или не закончатся попытки
    console.log(word);                              // Указание рандомно выбранного слова в консоле (если отгадать не получается, а проигрывать не хочется)
    alert("Букв в слове : " + answer.join(" "));   // Вывод сообщения, о количестве букв в консоле

    var choice = prompt("Введите 1 букву. Убедитесь, что используете русскую раскладку ! У вас осталось " + tries + " попыток");   // Окно со строкой ввода.
    if (choice === null) {                               // Если игрок нажмет отмену,
        break;                                       // то с помощью break мы выйдем из цикла.
    } else if (choice.length !== 1) {               // Проверяем, чтобы игрок ввёл только отдну букву
        alert("Это так не работает");                       // Сообщение, которое появится, если игрок введёт больше одной буквы.
    } else {
        var check = false;                           // Чек тут для того, чтобы потом можно было отнять попытку, если игрок ошибся
        for (var q = 0; q < word.length; q++) {                              // цикл, проверяем, все ли буквы отгадал игрок
            if (word[q] === choice && answer[q] === "_") {            
                answer[q] = choice;
                left--;
                check = true;
            } 
        }
        if (!check) tries--; // Отнимаем попытку при указании неверной буквы
    }
}

if (left === 0) {                                                    // Если не осталось букв, которые нужно отгадать, и сотались попытки,
    alert("Победа ! Отгаданное слово " + "'" + word + "'");         // то выводим это сообщение.
} else if (tries === 0){                                     // Если число оставшихся попыток равно 0,
    alert("Проигрыш : закончились попытки.");                        // то выводим это сообщение.
} else {
    alert("Ну нормально же играли...");                            // В случае, если игрок нажал на "отмена", то выводим это сообщение.
}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var check = false;
    choice = choice.toLowerCase();
    for (var q = 0; q < word.length; q++) {
```